# Insert Data Set into Oracle Table

Tags: c#, oracle, insert, dataset

I am trying to insert all the records from my data table into oracle table.  I have figured out how to insert a single record, however how do I go about inserting multiple records.  The biggest problem here is that the order of columns in dataset does not match the order of columns in oracle table.

Here is the code I am using to insert a single record:

```
OdbcCommand cmd = new OdbcCommand();
    try
    {
        cmd.Connection = getDBConnection(); //This calls another method that just gets the connection to database
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO MY_INSERT_TEST(NAME) VALUES(\'Test 1\')";
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        cmd.Connection.Close();
        cmd.Dispose();
    }
    catch
    {
        cmd.Connection.Close();
        cmd.Dispose();
    }
```

so how do I modify these to add all records from the data set?

Comment: Why do you use an OdbcConnection instead of the OracleConnection (Microsoft or Oracle providers)?

Comment: Why does this matters?

Comment: The order of the columns won't matter if you name them in the `INSERT`: `INSERT INTO myTable(Col3, Col1, Col2) VALUES ('value for Col3', 'value for Col1', 'value for Col2')`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Supposing you want to loop over a collection of rows and you want to insert all of them then I would try with a pseudocode like this.

```
string cmdText = "INSERT INTO MY_INSERT_TEST(Col1, Col2, Col3) VALUES(?, ?, ?)";
using(OdbcConnection cn = getDBConnection())
using(OdbcCommand cmd = new OdbcCommand(cmdText, cn))
{
    cn.Open();
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p1", "");
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p2", "");
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p3", "");
    foreach(DataRow r in dt.Rows)
    {
         cmd.Parameters["@p1"].Value =  r["Column3"].ToString());
         cmd.Parameters["@p2"].Value =  r["Column1"].ToString());
         cmd.Parameters["@p3"].Value =  r["Column2"].ToString());
         cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
}
```

Build a parameterized query, define the parameters (here are all parameters of string type, need to be checked) and then loop over the rows of the datatable assigning the parameters value from the corresponding column. Notice that in the command text you don't write directly the values but you put a placeholder for the actual value that you will supply inside the loop.

Comment: You need to test this code, I haven't an Oracle database here and as I have said this is a pseudocode to just show a possible solution