# Button onclick to insert textbox into oracle database

Tags: c#, .net, oracle

I am using C# .net and Vs2012 and need to get a button onclick to insert textbox into oracle database.

I am new to C# and .net but understand what needs to happen just don't know how to make it happen.

Comment: please post your code. What you have tried so far.

Comment: Insert textbox value you mean? Have a look at [Insert Data Set into Oracle Table](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17172106/insert-data-set-into-oracle-table)

Comment: 1) create a connection to the database 2) build a SQL statement 3) execute the SQL statement.  Google is loaded with examples.

Comment: it may helps you http://sqlblog.com/blogs/john_paul_cook/archive/2012/12/12/installing-oracle-11g-r2-on-64-bit-windows-7.aspx http://www.shabdar.org/c-sharp/101-connect-to-oracle-using-asp-net-and-csharp.html

Comment: This is what I am trying so far

Comment: @WebsterAlexanderIII: Do you still have issue with this?

Comment: yep and I am using an ODBC connection and while building it, it will insert a literal but I can't seem to get the code right to do it from my page with an onclick event.

Answer (score 0):

Example Only

Replace data accordingly i.e . UserId, Servername etc...

```
var conn = new OracleConnection("User Id=xxx;Password=xxx;Server=xxxx;");
var cmd = new OracleCommand();
cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO TABLENAME (COLUMN) VALUES (:1)";
cmd.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter("1",
                                   OracleDbType.Varchar2,
                                   txt.Text,
                                   ParameterDirection.Input));
cmd.Connection = conn;
conn.Open();
try 
{
  cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();      
}
catch 
{
  MessageBox.Show("Error");
}
finally 
{
  conn.Close();
}
```

Comment: doesn't work... Here is what I am trying <script runat="server"> protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) { try { SqlDataSource1.DataBind(); } catch { lblHello.Text = "Hello World"; } } </script>

Comment: My Connection <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:cfo_intranet.OCFODB %>" ProviderName="<%$ ConnectionStrings:cfo_intranet.OCFODB.ProviderName %>" SelectCommand="INSERTSUGGESTION" SelectCommandType="StoredProcedure">

    <SelectParameters>
        <asp:FormParameter DefaultValue="cat " FormField="EMAIL" Name="EMAIL" Type="String" />
        <asp:FormParameter DefaultValue="dog " FormField="SUGGESTION" Name="SUGGESTION" Type="String" />
    </SelectParameters>

    </asp:SqlDataSource>

Comment: I can get the submit button to write into a textbox so I know the button works... but when I go through the VB connection builder and not change a setting one, other than the default values, when I finish the connection it will write to the oracle db. When I go through the page it gives me nothing, no errors at all. I used the try catch and I get no catch... any suggestions?

Comment: got the insert working... and now I need an email to be sent to me when an item has been posted.

Comment: @WebsterAlexanderIII: You mean to generate an email after successful data insert?

Comment: Got it all figured out and will post the code the first of the week for others needing to do the same... Thanks for all the brain power!!!